# How can View properties be used in its template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

```
App.FolderListItemView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'folder-list-item',
        tagName: 'li',
        classNames: ['folder'],
        classNameBindings: ['opened'],
        opened: false,
        click: function (e) {
                this.set('opened', !this.get('opened'));
        }
});



<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="folder-list-item">
        <i {{bind-attr class="opened:icon-content-plus:icon-content-minus"}}></i>
        ...
</script>
```

I would like to change the icon (plus/minus) according to the value of 'opened' of the view.

The bind-attr does not work. How should I deal with this?

Comment: `opened` should be in your cotnroller.

Comment: `opened` is only UI-related and that's why I wouldn't like to relate it with the actual model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `view.opened` property in your template

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="folder-list-item">
        <i {{bind-attr class="view.opened:icon-content-plus:icon-content-minus"}}></i>
        ...
</script>
```